# Change Application version on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

I am trying to change application version from Windows Phone 8.1 to 8.0 and I can not see 8.0.

[image: Snapshot is here]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Thought Visual Studio 2013 can upgrade WP8.0 projects to WP8.1, the reverse operation isn't available. When you upgrade the WP8.0 project, you should see a popup window, which says that '*... this operation cannot be undone*'.

If you want to make a WP8.0 project then you will have to start a new project, select one of *(Windows Phone Silverlight)* and then, after clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>, the VS should ask you if you want this project to be WP8.0 or WP8.1. Once you select WP8.0, then you will also be able to upgrade it later to WP8.1.

Comment: I understand. I am wondering, can I change manually Package.appxmanifest file for solving problem ?

Comment: @OsmanVilli I haven't tried, but maybe it will be possible to change manually things to configure it for WP8.0. Look that there are more changes - WP8.0 doesn't have package.appxmanifest at all. I think you can try to create WP8.0 project, backup it, upgrade one to WP8.1, then compare the changes. I'm not sure if that would be possible, but you can try.

Comment: Problem has solved. I created new Windows Phone 8.0 project and wrote again. So copy paste code :) so thanks everything.

Comment: @OsmanVilli That was the easiest way - but dependant on your project size ;)